# getting empty response on sequelize findall from postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to node js environment and currently I am practicing a crud applicaiton
I am using sequelize as ORM and I have used the mvc structure

```
npm install --save sequelize
$ npm install --save pg pg-hstore
```

I am using sequelize cli

```
npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli

npx sequelize-cli init
```

**It is my migration**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Books', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Books');
  }
};
```

**My Model:**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Books extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Books.init({
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Books',
  });
  return Books;
};
```

**MY Controller:**

```
exports.allBooks = (req,res)=>{
const bookme = Books(**how to pass sequelize**,**how to pass sequelize datatype**)
    var booksJSON = bookme.findAll()
res.json(booksJSON)
console.log(JSON.stringify(booksJSON))
}
```

I am getting the empty response if I pass the datatypes customly by creating a connection manually to database with sequelize and passing that sequelize to the books models
I think that my mistake is in passing these parameters. What and how shoudld I pass to the Books model

**I am importing the books model as follows in my controller:**

```
const Books = require('../models/books.js');
```

also when i ran the bootstraping that created migrations,models,seeding folders it also created a index.js file in models folder
I have tried passing that too in the parameter to Books model but It gave error

**index.js in models folder created by sequelize cli package itself**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

The error I got when I try to pass this db from index.js to Books model in my controller is:

```
 const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
                                                     ^

TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

***What should I pass to the parameter and from where?***

Answer (score 0):

I am getting response by using aysnc and await. I used second parameter by importing directly from the package
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

and for first parameter I used the manually created connection.
**but it still doesn't clears my concern of actually what parameters were to pass**